# Capture content of html-tags

Tags: php, html, regex

I need a regex to match the content in a tag without the tag.

```
<p>content1<a>content2 <span>content3</span></a> content4</p>
<a href="link">content1 <span>content2</span> content3</a>
```

For the moment I got `<.[^>]*>(.*?)<` . But the tag is captured.
I want to match content1 content2 ...
Thanks.

Comment: You said you need `content AND the subcontent`. Last sentence is `BUT subcontent is captured`. Thats an opposition. So do you need the subcontent or not?

Comment: Sorry I mean I want to exclude the <tag></tag>. Edited.

Comment: Please show the exact result you want to get.

Comment: Consider in using an html parser. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @mrdotb Your expression IS matching all contentes as you asked for. Check it here: https://regex101.com/r/xT2cL2/1

Comment: Look again the subtag contents is not matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find a way to capture the content without the subtag.

```
$html = fread($handle, filesize($argv[1]));⏎
preg_match_all('/<p[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>|<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/', $html, $matchs);
foreach ($matchs[0] as $content)
  echo strip_tags($content);
//With the html upper I get all the content
```

Reconsider downvote please I never ask question on stackoverflow without searching a lot first...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex pattern for that just assign any id to P tag or get the P tag using jquery and try following.

```
<p id="test">content1<a>content2 <span>content3</span></a> content4</p>
```

and in javascript add

```
var result = document.getElementById("test").innerText
```

Comment: Thanks but I want a regex. It' text data not on a html page.